# Resolving paths in mingw fails with Data Version Control

Tags: windows, mingw, dvc

I am following the [tutorial](https://blog.dataversioncontrol.com/data-version-control-tutorial-9146715eda46) about [Data Version Control](https://github.com/iterative/dvc) using `mingw32` on Windows 7.

I am getting very strange error when I try to use [run](https://dvc.org/doc/commands-reference/run):

```
$ dvc run -v echo "hello"
Debug: updater is not old enough to check for updates
Debug: PRAGMA user_version;
Debug: fetched: [(2,)]
Debug: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state (inode INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mtime TEXT NOT NULL, md5 TEXT NOT NULL, timestamp TEXT NOT NULL)
Debug: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state_info (count INTEGER)
Debug: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS link_state (path TEXT PRIMARY KEY, inode INTEGER NOT NULL, mtime TEXT NOT NULL)
Debug: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO state_info (count) SELECT 0 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM state_info)
Debug: PRAGMA user_version = 2;
Running command:
        echo hello
/c: /c: Is a directory
Debug: SELECT count from state_info WHERE rowid=1
Debug: fetched: [(1,)]
Debug: UPDATE state_info SET count = 1 WHERE rowid = 1
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dvc\command\run.py", line 18, in run
  File "dvc\project.py", line 265, in run
  File "dvc\stage.py", line 435, in run
StageCmdFailedError: Stage 'Dvcfile' cmd echo hello failed

Error: Failed to run command: Stage 'Dvcfile' cmd echo hello failed
```

#### Question:

Where does the `/c: /c: Is a directory` come from?  How can I fix it?

#### My findings

1. I supposed that it was resolving path to echo, but ech is a builtin.

   ```
   $ type echo
   echo is a shell builtin
   ```

   I tried also with `exit` and `cd` but I am getting the same error.
2. Calling commands without dvc works fine.
3. `dvc` with `--no-exec` flag works fine, but when later executed with `repro` gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the dvc developers. Similar error has affected dvc running on cygwin. We've released a fix for it in `0.20.0`. Please upgrade.